# How can I get eggs from Pokestops more often?

Tags: pokemon-go

A few days ago, I stopped receiving eggs. I am still able to visit Pokestops (and get potions, balls, etc) and I have been actively hatching eggs in incubators, but even when my bag is not full, for a dozen or more Pokestops, I haven't received a single egg to replenish any of the 6 I have recently hatched (I am down to 3/9 eggs).

Does anyone know why egg distribution may have stopped? Is there a maximum number of eggs you are ever provided? If not, and it's just bad luck, is there some way for me to get more eggs reliably?

Comment: It's just RNG, man. Nothing has changed.

Comment: I got eggs today, so I can confirm it's not coming from the game. As Vemonus said, bad RNG there. Keep spamming those Pokéstops.

Comment: I suggested an edit which I think gets to the heart of what you're asking and will prevent more down votes. Feel free to revert if it doesn't clarify what you were asking. .

Answer (score 6):

If you are having a rough time with the random stop rewards not giving you an egg, you can force the game to give you one by hitting ten unique stops in a row. If you do this, you get extra items, double xp, and a guaranteed egg on the tenth stop. There is a time limit (30 min?), so do this in an area with a bunch of stops so that you can hit ten different ones quickly.

One other thing that can cause this is being maxed out on Pokemon (not items), since eggs count towards that limit.

Other than that, it's just luck. There's nothing you can do to get a higher chance to get an egg, and you haven't hit a max or anything like that.